# Disable PreserveCultureAttribute in Hangfire

Tags: c#, hangfire

I am trying to use Hangfire to send a scheduled message to a user using the MS Bot Framework. However, all scheduled jobs fail with this:

```
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException

Culture is not supported. Parameter name: name en-HK is an invalid culture identifier.

System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
en-HK is an invalid culture identifier.
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at Hangfire.CaptureCultureAttribute.OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
   at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
```

Hangfire docs say that it's due to Culture Preserving and "It is done by the PreserveCultureAttribute class that is applied to all of your methods by default."

http://docs.hangfire.io/en/v1.1.0/features.html?highlight=preservecultureattribute

How can I disable the PreserveCultureAttribute in Hangfire so that it doesn't apply it to my methods?

Comment: But why does CultureNotFoundException occurs? Thread is always running under valid culturename. You posted that PreserveCultureAttribute is applied by default. Although PreserveCultureAttribute doesn't exist anymore in Hangifre 1.4.6, I only found CaptureCulture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I disable the PreserveCultureAttribute in Hangfire so that it doesn't apply it to my methods?

I don't know exactly how to disable it but you can play with `[PreserveCulture]` attribute. Base on the exception you post I think the culture code is wrong. Check this [link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/) for correct culture code. Culture code for HK should be `zh-HK`.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("zh-HK");
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => NotifyNewComment(model.Id));

[PreserveCulture]
public static void NotifyNewComment(int commentId)
{
    var currentCultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
    if (currentCultureName != "zh-HK")
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Current culture is {0}", currentCultureName));
    }
}
```

See reference https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/77.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me so far. By default, the `Thread Culture` is set to system culture so it needs to be changed on application startup.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove default filters like this:

```
var filter = GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Where(x => x.Instance is CaptureCultureAttribute).Single().Instance;
GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Remove(filter);
```